Irrigation system vs weed prevention
When installing drip irrigation,  how do you mow around to keep from damaging systems or do you bury the system?

It depends on the system. Could you add more information (and maybe a picture)?

I have approximately 150 blueberry bushes and was gifted a drip irrigation system. I only mulch around the bushes. I haven't installed the system yet because of the mowing issue.

So, there is lawn between the bushes? I would bury the lines, and have the "drip" part only near the bushes. 150 seems a lot (length, and water usage), already in the professional use (where aesthetics is less important), in such case, pipes may be larger (no risk to damage): you move left or right then you lawn. A photo will help, not sure I can get the image of what you really have

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Usually you do not install drip irrigation on lawns. It is usually used for hedges, flower beds, vegetables, crops.
There are some drip irrigation for lawns, but usually installed underground, and possibly with a sheet of plastic to keep humidity and preventing deep root on some weeds. The most common automatic irrigation for lawns is sprinkler systems, and the head should be underground. Water pressure should be able to lift the head when watering.

Use more mulch, and have no grass.
Pull weeds, including grass, which is a weed in blueberries; do not mow.
Nearly all drip systems do not recommend burial for the emitters, as they can become clogged with dirt. If the particular system uses emitters connected to lines that don't themselves have emitters, you can bury the lines. If it uses drip line with emitters built into the line, it is not recommended to bury it.
